# Mass/Charge ratio of a black hole

Tags: black-holes, charge, mass, reissner-nordstrom-metric

Which order of  mass/charge ratio must a black hole have to become overfed?

Comment: You can figure it out using the condition for an extremal charged black hole, $2r_Q=r_s$, given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric#Charged_black_holes), plus the definitions $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ and $r_Q^2=\frac{Q^2 G}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^4}$.